# Using descriptors in a superclass to avoid code duplication in subclasses

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-descriptors

In python, I have a base class from which I have derived a set of subclasses. Each subclass has some subclass-specific functions and a number of unique properties, which have getters and setters defined using `@property` decorators. But if I have many properties, that leads to lots of code duplication, since the getters and setters all have the same form. Here's a rough example sketch, using database access as an example:

```
class BaseClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.handle = None

    def write(self, **kwargs):
        self.handle.write(**kwargs)

class subClass_1(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.handle = db_connector("table1")

    @property
    def property1a(self):
        return self.handle.read('columnX')

    @property1a.setter
    def property1a(self, data):
        self.write(columnX=data)

    @property
    def property1b(self):
        return self.handle.read('columnY')

    @property1b.setter
    def property1b(self, data):
        self.write(columnY=data)

    def some_bespoke_function():
        pass

class subClass_2(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.handle = db_connector("table2")

    @property
    def property2a(self):
        return self.handle.read('columnZ')

    @property2a.setter
    def property2a(self, data):
        self.write(columnZ=data)

    def another_bespoke_function():
        pass
```

is there any way I can define something in the BaseClass to avoid having to write all those `@property` decorators? Ideally, I'd just define something in the subclass like `self.mapping = {'property1a':'columnX', 'property1a':'columnX'}` for SubClass_1 and `self.mapping = {'property2a':'columnZ'}` for SubClass_2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: the solution seems to be to use `__getattr__` in the base class, which (I didn't realise) is only called if the attribute *does not exist*. So the key here is (strangely) *not* to define the properties at all, but trap reading and writing calls to these non-existing "properties", and fire off the function as needed. No need for decorators at all:

```
class BaseClass():
    col_mapping = {}
    def __init__(self):
        self.handle = None

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in col_mapping:
            return self.handle.read(col_mapping[name])
        raise AttributeError

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in col_mapping:
            self.handle.write(**{col_mapping[name]:value})
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

    def write(self, **kwargs):
        self.handle.write(**kwargs)

class subClass_1(BaseClass):
    col_mapping = {
        'property1a':'columnX',
        'property1b':'columnY'
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.handle = db_connector("table1")

    def some_bespoke_function():
        pass

class subClass_2(BaseClass):
    col_mapping = {
        'property2a':'columnZ'
    }
    def __init__(self):
        self.handle = db_connector("table2")

    def another_bespoke_function():
        pass
```